# Isolate/Sum Data Conditionally Based On Event Sequence

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that tracks events sequentially and calculates the time for each event. What I want to do using the below sample data, is calculate the total number of Time Elapse (Seconds) of all Event A's that happened **before** the second Event C occurred.  So in the below example, I'd want an output of 550 seconds.

Obviously,

```
select sum(timeelapse_seconds) where eventtype = "A"
```

returns a result of 750 seconds because it includes event # 6.

```
Event EventType TimeElapse_Seconds
----------------------------------    
  1        C          50
  1        A         100
  2        A         100
  3        B         200
  4        A         350
  5        C         100
  6        A         200
```

Thanks!

**Update**

Apologies as I just realized something about my data set. There will be an initial Event 1 with EventType C. So, I need to find the second instance rather than the first (so min does not work). I've updated the sample table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT SUM(TimeElapse_Seconds) TotalElapse_Seconds
FROM (
  SELECT EventType, TimeElapse_Seconds, 
    COUNTIF(EventType = 'C') OVER(ORDER BY Event) = 1 BeforeC
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE EventType = 'A' AND BeforeC
```

If to apply to sample data from your questin  - result is

```
Row TotalElapse_Seconds  
1   550
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you have to find the position of the Second appearance of event C, and then sum the value of TimeElapse_Seconds for all the A events with index minor to that position. So:

```
SELECT SUM(TimeElapse_Seconds)
FROM events
WHERE EventType = 'A' 
AND Event < (SELECT MIN(Event) -- Second appearance of event C
             FROM events
             WHERE EventType = 'C' 
               AND Event > (SELECT MIN(Event) -- First appearance of event C
                            FROM events
                            WHERE EventType = 'C'))
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use window functions:

```
select sum(TimeElapse_Seconds)
from (select t.*,
             min(case when eventtype = 'C' then event end) over (order by event) as min_c_event
      from t
     ) t
where event < min_c_event and event = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Event` determines ordering for determining what *before* means...

```
SELECT sum(TimeElapse_Seconds)
FROM events
WHERE EventType = 'A' AND Event < (SELECT min(Event) FROM events WHERE EventType = 'C');
```

is one way. For best results you'll want an index on `(EventType, Event)`